# Executing an oracle grant in c# using ExecuteSqlCommand and OracleParameter

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am trying to execute a grant using Entity Frameworks "ExecuteSqlCommand". In this grant statement the grantee is variable.
Assume the following query as the grant statement:

```
grant all on employee to :variableScheme with grant option
```

if execute the following code I get the error "ORA-00987: missing or invalid username(s)"

```
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(grantQuery, new object [] { Parameter });
```

However, if I use the string.Replace method and then execute above code(without the oracle parameter) it works. If I use ExecuteSqlCommand on an insert/update statement with parameters it also works.

Why does the use of OracleParameter give an error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use user name as bind parameter. You must concatenate the string:

```
grantQuery = String.Format("grant all on employee to {0} with grant option", variableScheme );
```